# $_files['photo']; is empty

Tags: php, upload

I was trying to make an image upload script but $_files['photo']; is empty all the way.

```
$_FILES['photo']['name'];
$_FILES['photo']['size'];
$_FILES['photo']['type'];
$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
$_FILES['photo']['error'];
```

When I echo them out, they all return absolutely nothing.

```
if($_FILES['photo']['name'])
{

if(!$_FILES['photo']['error'])
{
    $new_file_name = strtolower($_FILES['photo']['name']); 
    if($_FILES['photo']['size'] > (1024000)) 
    {
        $valid_file = false;
        $msg = 'Oops!  Your file\'s size is to large.';
        echo $msg;
    }

    if($valid_file)
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], 'images/thumbnails/'.$new_file_name);
        $msg = 'Congratulations!  Your file was accepted.';
        echo $msg;
    }
}

else
{
    $msg = 'Ooops!  Your upload triggered the following error:  '.$_FILES['photo']['error'];
    echo $msg;
}
}
```

Did I do something wrong maybe?

```
<form action='?p=post' method='POST'>
            <input type='file' name='photo' size='25' />
            <input type='submit' value='Posten' name='submit' /><br />
            </form>
```

Comment: Probably your form's file element isn't named, and/or your form doesn't have a proper enctype, and/or no post method. Let's see the form you're using.

Comment: Edited the form in. But I didn't know that I had to use enctype. No Idea if that was the problem, will try thanks.

Comment: I've posted my answer for you below.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form is missing an essential part => `enctype="multipart/form-data"` add it in your form.

```
<form action='?p=post' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

- The data encoding type is required when uploading files.

Consult:

- **http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php**